# Excel UDF Loop to find specific value from a string in a range

Tags: excel, vba

In Cell A1 i have a description of a computer (HDD, Proccessor, GFX etc) and in cells B1-10 i have a list of proccessors, what i want is an excel UDF that would looke like this in cell C1:

GetProccessor(A1,B1:B10)

I know i need to parse in in VBA with:

Function GetProccessor(Text as Variant, rRange as Range)

Then i am stuck as i am very poor with range loops, could anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: @Sam This feels a lot like the previous question you asked. Is your intention either 1) that the function in cell C1 should *return* a value for C1 (this is probably ideal) or 2) that the function in cell C1 should *change* the value in cell B1-B10?  The latter option is impossible with a UDF, as I described in my answer to your other question.  However, the former option will work and would be a better practice.

Comment: Hi Ben, I havent asked a question, probably the same details as someone else! I found the solution myself in the end, simple just misunderstood some of the examples i read... 

Answer posted below

Comment: Sam:  This is a Q+A site, you are supposed to ask a question.  Your answer makes no sense because you never defined a problem/question for it to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Get Parts Function, worked it out myself!

```
Function GetPart(text As Variant, rCells As Range)
  Dim txt As String
  Dim rRange As Range
  Dim SubjCell

  For Each rRange In rCells
    SubjCell = rRange
    txt = text

    If InStr(txt, SubjCell) <> 0 Then
      GetPart = SubjCell
      Exit For
    Else
      GetPart = "Not Found"
    End If
  Next rRange

End Function
```